# Python3 http.server : save log to a file

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, stdout

I use Python3.6 to write a simple HTTP server to redirect all requests.

The file I written can be found [here](https://github.com/kmahyyg/learn_py3/blob/master/antiscanhttp.py)

I can see output in both Win8.1 CMD & Ubuntu 16.04.3 Bash.
However , whatever I try any of those methods below , it doesn't work , the log cannot be saved into the file.

```
nohup python3 ./filename.py > ./logfile 2>&1 &
python3 ./filename.py > ./logfile 2>&1 &
setsid ./filename.py > ./logfile 2>&1 &
```

I tried to use:

```
import sys
logfile = open('logfile.log','w')
sys.stdout = logfile
sys.stdin = logfile
sys.stderr = logfile
```

It didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? If you're trying to read the file while the server is running then the output probably hasn't been flushed yet

Comment: Nope. I mean that I tried to run it and after several hours , the logfile is still empty. I have to see the log like this > 2017/1/1 GET / - 301 . However , I see nothing in the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Python's stdout and stderr are buffered. As other responders have noted, if your log files are empty then (assuming your logging is correct) the output has not been flushed.

The link to the script is no longer valid, but you can try running your script either as `python3 -u filename.py` or the equivalent `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x python3 filename.py`. This causes the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered.

A full example that uses the standard library's `http.server` module to serve files from the current directory:

`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x python3 -m http.server &> http.server.log & echo $! > http.server.pid`

All output (stdout & stderr) is redirected to *http.server.log*, which can be tailed, and the process ID of the server is written to *http.server.pid* so that you can kill the process by `kill $(cat http.server.pid)`.

Answer (score 1):

i've tried your code on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked like charm.

```
import sys
logfile = open('logfile.log','w')
sys.stdout = logfile
sys.stdin = logfile
sys.stderr = logfile
```

Comment: See the screenshot here.Maybe there's some shortage of dependencies ? https://i.loli.net/2017/10/11/59dd7aa56f3ca.jpg

Comment: @PotatoChips have you read the manual page for nohup? nohup redirects away from the terminal, so trying direct the remaining output (of which where is none) into a log file won't give you anything in that log file. And in the other case your server is still running so it might not have been flushed. So run it without nohup and shut it down, then check the output. If you need to read the log while the server is running, make sure the output is being flushed.

Comment: I tried to run without nohup , and after serveral hours I killed the process.The log file still remains empty.