# Why grep ignores the first line of "python3 -m http.server" output?

Tags: bash, grep, stdin, io-redirection

For some reason grep will not print the first line of the output of the command:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

```bash
python3 -m http.server
# prints: Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...


python3 -m http.server | grep -E .
# nothing is printed


python3 -m http.server 2>&1 | grep -E .
# nothing is printed
```

However if I perform a request I can see the rest of the logs (but not the first line):

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2023 11:07:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Why is this happening? Is there a way to print the first line with grep? (note: The same problem appears when piping to `tail`)

Answer (score 1):

It seems python stdout and stderr are buffered by default, try:

```bash
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x python3 -m http.server 2>&1 | grep -E .
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52236578/13339621)